# M2: Issue with filter by brands

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

We have any issue with filter products by brand:
https://b2bstyle.pl/shoes-woman/sandals.html

During select brand return "No products found".

Anyone know where is issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you reindex all index and clean all cache?

Comment: Yes of course. I will try this.